# ACF meta_value assigning page id

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have:

```
$idofpost = get_the_ID();


// args
$args = array(
'numberposts'   => -1,
'post_type'     => 'products',
'meta_key'      => 'product_designer',
'meta_value' => '" . $idofpost . "'
);
```

If I echo $idofpost I get 38 for example. If I type in 38 for meta_value it works just fine, but not by using this variable - any ideas? It looks like it should work just fine?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'product_designer',
        'value' => "$post->ID",
        'compare' => '='
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write Your code as below:

```
$idofpost = get_the_ID();

// args
$args = array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_type'   => 'products',
            'meta_key'    => 'product_designer',
            'meta_value'  => $idofpost
        );
```